# Javascript: How to transfer variables between code blocks?

Tags: javascript

I am using Mautic which is an email newsletter software. Users enter their details for the newsletter via HTML landing pages that contains a simple HTML form.

This JS code allows Mautic to process the data from the HTML landing page. It is placed right before the closing body tag of my HTML page:

**Mautic Code Block**

```
<script>
    (function(w,d,t,u,n,a,m){w['MauticTrackingObject']=n;
        w[n]=w[n]||function(){(w[n].q=w[n].q||[]).push(arguments)},a=d.createElement(t),
        m=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];a.async=1;a.src=u;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','https://myurl/mtc.js','mt');
       mt('send', 'pageview', {'tags':'landing-page-name'});

</script>
```

The last line `'tags':'landing-page-name'` tells Mautic from which landing page the inputted data has come from. At the moment, `landing-page-name` has to be hardcoded in. I would prefer it if `landing-page-name` could be dynamically replaced with the file name of the HTML page.

On my HTML page, I already have a Javascript block that extracts the file name of the current HTML page and inserts it into a field on my Mautic form (on the HTML landing page). It assigns the name of the HTML page to a variable called `val`.

**HTML Name Code Block**

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        let val = location.pathname.split('/').pop().replace('.html', '');
        val = val.replace(/-/g, ' ');
        val = val.replace(/(^\w{1})|(\s{1}\w{1})/g, match => match.toUpperCase());
        document.getElementById('mauticform_input_genericcouponclub_book_purchased').value = val;
        document.getElementById('mauticform_genericcouponclub_book_purchased').style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```

This code block is directly placed above the Mautic Code Block.

How can I pass the `val` variable into the Mautic Code Block, so I can use in the 'tags': part rather than having to hardcode the name?

Comment: I don't know how that software works so there may be a better way but, of course, the most straightforward mechanism would be to make it global to window rather than local to the onload callback function.

Answer (score 0):

Add filename to global/window object. Access the same variable in other functions.

Make sure you wrap second function(consumer) in `windows.load` as well because file name will be undefined before that. Alternatively you can have a fallback name.

```js
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        let val = location.pathname.split('/').pop().replace('.html', '');
        val = val.replace(/-/g, ' ');
        val = val.replace(/(^\w{1})|(\s{1}\w{1})/g, match => match.toUpperCase());
        document.getElementById('mauticform_input_genericcouponclub_book_purchased').value = val;
        document.getElementById('mauticform_genericcouponclub_book_purchased').style.display = "none";

// attach name to window/global object
    window.htmlFileName = val;
    }
    
    
</script> 

-----------------------

<script>
 window.onload = function() {
    var fileName = window.htmlFileName || 'landing-page-name'
    (function(w,d,t,u,n,a,m){w['MauticTrackingObject']=n;
        w[n]=w[n]||function(){(w[n].q=w[n].q||[]).push(arguments)},a=d.createElement(t),
        m=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];a.async=1;a.src=u;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','https://myurl/mtc.js','mt');
       mt('send', 'pageview', {'tags': fileName });
}
</script>
```